# Some [django] version tags are more misused than used correctly

Tags: discussion, tags

I'm going to talk specifically about the [django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django) version tags. I recently went through the tagged questions for [django-2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django-2.2), the current LTS release. I edited around 60 or so, but it quickly got extremely boring and I lost all hope.

Almost every question misused the tag. The few that didn't were in two categories:

- How to deploy version x of Django on <some hosting provider> - I would argue these are mostly not version specific either since the deployment process doesn't really change between versions.
- A problem encountered when upgrading between two versions - legitimate, but there aren't that many of them.

I would estimate at least 90% - probably more - of questions with this tag were misused. This is a bad experience in every way:

- In theory, someone has to clean this up. In practice, it doesn't seem to happen often. So the tags remain incorrectly used.
- Users often apply the [django-2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django-2.2) tag, but not the [django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django) tag. Their questions end up going into a black hole of sorts because far more people watch the [django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django) tag than the version tags, so often their question doesn't attract enough views to get answered.
- Which may lead to users leaving, thinking they can't get answers here.

I propose to just drop all the Django version tags. I don't see the harm in people asking version-specific questions on the general tag, because:

- There's not too many of them, so not much noise for the general tag.
- They attract more answers.
- Questions legitimately using a version tag usually also have the [django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django) tag anyway, so even if you really want to ignore those questions you'd also have to exclude every version tag.

The juice doesn't seem to be worth the squeeze.

It's also important to point out I'm not making the case for removing version tags in general. The [python-2.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-2.x) and [python-3.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-3.x) tags are very useful, because Python 2 holds many versions, as does 3, there are significant differences between them, and people have been extremely slow to migrate from 2 to 3.

Comment: Re *"...got extremely boring and I lost all hope"*: Perhaps concentrate on the ones with [the highest view rate](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/164178/highest-view-rate-questions-in-a-particular-tag-non-community-wiki)? As it is most likely a [power law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_law), you could achieve 99.95% of the impact by editing 0.03% of the questions (just an example; the actual constant in the power law is probably different).